# How to make a line as a comment in SED

Tags: unix, sed, comments

Excuse me if it is a repeat. I have crontab entries which look like:

```
*   *    *    *    *   sleep 15;/etc/opt/wer.sh
1 * * * * /opt/sfm/qwe/as.sh
```

How to insert a # on the line which contains a call to "as.sh" using **sed**?
How to uncomment it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed '/\/as.sh/s/^/#/'
```

which will replace the start-line zero-width marker with a comment character for all lines containing `/as.sh`, as shown in the following example:

```
pax> echo '
* * * * * sleep 15;/etc/opt/wer.sh
1 * * * * /opt/sfm/qwe/as.sh
' | sed '/\/as.sh/s/^/#/'

* * * * * sleep 15;/etc/opt/wer.sh
#1 * * * * /opt/sfm/qwe/as.sh
```

But you need to keep in mind a couple of things.

- It's usually not enough to just change the file, you also need to notify `cron` that it needs to re-read it. This is automatic if you use the `crontab` command itself but you may have to send a signal to `cron` if you're editing the file directly.
- It's not always a good idea to turn scripts loose on important system files. Make sure you know what you're doing and don't trust any old codger on the net (*including* me). Test it thoroughly.

To get rid of the marker, use:

```
sed '/\/as.sh/s/^#//'
```

This is the opposite operation, it finds those lines containing `/as.sh` and substitute any `#` character at the start of the line with nothing.

Answer (score 3):

To add the comment:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)\(as.sh\)/\#\1\2/g"
```

To remove the comment:

```
sed -e "s/\(^#\)\(.*\)\(as.sh\)/\2\3/g"
```

Answer (score -2):

use crontab -e to modify the current user's crontab.