# sed: toggle comments in crontab

Tags: unix, sed, awk, cron

My goal is to create a script which does the following alterations to a crontab. Any uncommented cron entries are commented, while any commented entries are uncommented. My crontab comments have no numbers in them, so I believe the logic I have set out is sound:

1) Back up the crontab
2) Make changes to the crontab

- If the line starts with any number, comment the line
- If the line starts with a comment followed by a number, uncomment the line
  3) Reload the crontab.

I specifically need help with step 2. I have used this to comment ALL lines, but I am finding it difficult to get any further:

```
sed -i 's/^\([^#]\)/#\1/g' Crontab.txt
```

Would anyone have any advice on achieving my objectives above? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368955/how-to-make-a-line-as-a-comment-in-sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` to toggle comments easily.

```
sed -i '# If line is a comment, uncomment
    # (replace \s with [    ] if your sed does not support \s for whitespace)
    s/^\s*#//
    # If the previous action did something, skip the rest
    t
    # If we are still here, comment out this entry
    s/^/#/' Crontab.txt
```

If your `sed` dialect doesn't understand `\s` you can use the alternative `[...]` expression from the comment instead.  (That's a space and a tab inside the brackets.  You can enter a literal tab with <kbd>ctrl-V tab</kbd> in many shells.)

To only toggle where the first non-comment character is a number, adapt the regex slightly.

```
sed -i 's/#\([0-9]\)/\1/;t;s/^\([0-9]\)/#\1/' Crontab.txt
```

Again, some dialectal variations exist; not all `sed` implementations require the backslash before the grouping parentheses, and not all `sed` implementations like semicolons as statement separators.  The main beef here is the use of a backreference to capture the number and refer to it in the replacement.

(An asterisk is also an allowed character in the first field of a crontab entry; just add that after `0-9` in both places if you want to include it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing it in 3 steps:

1. replace leading `#` in commented lines with some special text
2. prefix all lines which do not have the special text with `#`
3. remove the special text